# How do I create a Redux type for this data structure?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

How do I create an interface or type for this type of data structure to store into redux?

```
{
    "22": [{
        "pageId": "interiorother",
        "rowControls": []
    }, {
        "pageId": "someotherkey",
        "rowControls": []
    }],
    "23": [{
        "pageId": "interiorother",
        "rowControls": []
    }, {
        "pageId": "someotherkey",
        "rowControls": []
    }]
}
```

I tried this: const initialState:

```
{[key: string]: []} = { '': [] };
```

but my eslint is telling me to use a Record over an index signature. And when I ignore that, I'm having trouble with setting my object like so:

```
setAuditId: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state = { ...state[action.payload] = [] };
      return state;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this;

```
interface dttype {
  [key: string]: Array<{ pageId: string; rowControls: Array<string> }>;
}
```

I am asuming that the `rowControls` is an array of strings here.